# Setup OpenVPN 2.4 server and client to a complete unencrypted connection

Tags: openvpn, centos7

Despite the obvious security concern, I'd like to establish a completely unencrypted connection between my personal openvpn 2.4 server (on CentOS 7.4) with my windows OpenVPN 2.4 client.
I have been looking for the answer everywhere and tried multiple settings, but they either caused the server to fail starting up or the client to not connect at all.
I have found some information about adding `ncp-disable` to the server configuration, comment out the different `tls` lines in the server configuration file etc.
I also read some information about `alg=none` but I have no idea how to add that to the file/s.

This is my client ovpn:

```
client
proto udp
remote MYSERVER.COM 1194
dev tun
resolv-retry infinite
nobind
persist-key
persist-tun
remote-cert-tls server
verify-x509-name server_s5sK0KI7nHgwhrN name
auth SHA1
# auth SHA256
# auth none
auth-nocache
# cipher AES-128-CBC
cipher none
tls-client
tls-version-min 1.2
tls-cipher TLS-DHE-RSA-WITH-AES-128-GCM-SHA256
setenv opt block-outside-dns
verb 3
<ca>
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
REMOVED
-----END CERTIFICATE-----
</ca>
<cert>
REMOVED
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
REMOVED
-----END CERTIFICATE-----
</cert>
<key>
-----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-----
REMOVED
-----END PRIVATE KEY-----
</key>
key-direction 1
<tls-auth>
#
# 2048 bit OpenVPN static key
#
-----BEGIN OpenVPN Static key V1-----
REMOVED
-----END OpenVPN Static key V1-----
</tls-auth>
```

This is the server config:

```
port 1194
proto udp
dev tun
# auth none
# cipher none
# ncp-disable
user nobody
group nobody
persist-key
persist-tun
keepalive 10 120
topology subnet
server 10.8.0.0 255.255.255.0
ifconfig-pool-persist ipp.txt
push "dhcp-option DNS 8.8.8.8"
push "dhcp-option DNS 8.8.4.4"
push "redirect-gateway def1 bypass-dhcp" 
crl-verify crl.pem
ca ca.crt
cert server_s5sK0KI7nHgwhrN.crt
key server_s5sK0KI7nHgwhrN.key
tls-auth tls-auth.key 0
dh dh.pem
# auth SHA256
auth SHA1
# cipher AES-128-CBC
cipher none
tls-server
tls-version-min 1.2
tls-cipher TLS-DHE-RSA-WITH-AES-128-GCM-SHA256
# tls-cipher none
status openvpn.log
log-append openvpn.log
verb 3
```

Despite stating in both files `cipher none` it keeps connecting with AES-256-GCM cipher on:

```
Tue May 08 23:31:44 2018 Data Channel: using negotiated cipher 'AES-256-GCM'
Tue May 08 23:31:44 2018 Outgoing Data Channel: Cipher 'AES-256-GCM' initialized with 256 bit key
Tue May 08 23:31:44 2018 Incoming Data Channel: Cipher 'AES-256-GCM' initialized with 256 bit key
```

How can I configure them to connect completely unencrypted?

Comment: I'm not sure that's even possible. If you specifically want something that is so insecure your grandmother can break it, use PPTP.

Comment: I was considering it, but PPTP does not allow me to do some things I need to do with my router firmware and can do with OpenVPN, and there are other issues. I know disabling cipher is absolutely possible and was very easy to do on OpenVPN 2.3, but I don't know how to do that with 2.4

Comment: The two settings `cipher none` and `ncp-disable` _on the server_ should force an unencrypted tunnel, but I don't have a test-bed to check this on 2.4.

Comment: Maybe try to RTFS (read the fathomable source)? It's often the quickest solution for non-standard configs, plus it's a definitive solution.